# Using Tcl to create a filtered list from an existing list using a pattern in Tcl

Tags: tcl

My goal is to take a an existing list and then create a filter list based on a specific pattern. I do not want to use a for loop or while loop.

Example of what I want

```
set existing_list [list "color_blue12312" "color_blue32311" "color_green123j11" "color_green234321" "color_purple213123" "color_purple234234234"]

set purple_list [lsearch existing_list color_purple*]
puts $purple_list
```

This should print in the terminal:

```
color_purple213123 color_purple234234234
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `-all` (Returns all matches) and `-inline` (Returns the matched element(s), not indices) options to `lsearch`:

```
set existing_list {color_blue12312 color_blue32311 color_green123j11
    color_green234321 color_purple213123 color_purple234234234}
set purple_list [lsearch -all -inline $existing_list color_purple*]
puts $purple_list
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do such filtering. One, when you're using string matching patterns (equality, globbing, regular expressions) is `lsearch -all -inline`; Shawn's answer covers that (and I *absolutely* endorse that!). The other approach, which is vital when you want any other filtering rule, is to use `lmap` and to `continue` when you want a value to *not* be passed through.

```
set purple_list [lmap value $existing_list {
    if {[string match color_purple* $value]} {
        # the result of the 'if' is the contents of 'value'
        string cat $value
    } else {
        continue
    }
}]
```

This works because `lmap` is really just a `foreach` that collects the results in a list when the script has a normal (`TCL_OK`) completion; exceptional completions (such as `continue` uses) don't get collected.

---

Before you ask, yes, you can do filtering and mapping in a single sweep. And use multiple input lists and multiple variables to consume several elements per step. Why would you not?